# Datagrid is not generating columns when itemssource is Queryable or Enumrable on some Computers

Tags: wpf, datagrid, iqueryable, enumerable, autogeneratecolumn

for this example , my computer generate automatic columns, but in others machines, 
columns are not generating  if source is Queryable or Enumrable .

what can be the different

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dg.DataContext = GetPaople();
    }

    public object GetPaople()
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "F" +  i, LastName = "L" + i, Id = i });
        }
        var res = from p in list select p;
        return res.AsQueryable();//not Genrating Columns
        return list;//Genrating Columns
    }
```

Comment: The columns are generated based on the properties in Person. The .AsQueryable method makes it an IEnumarble which does not return a result if it is not accessed. I guess the DataGrid does not trigger the enumeration for you and the only way of autogenerating the columns is to return a collection.

Comment: What is the functional problem you are trying to solve?   What does List<Person> not provide?

Comment: Agree with @Silvermind and @Blam, a LINQ query must be **accessed** using extensions like .Count(), .ToList(), .ToArray() etc., only then it will evaluate into a collection. Why dont you use your `List` as it is? Do you want to make datagrid's itemssource `IQueryable` so that it performs sorting, filtering and grouping fast using expressions? Thats a good suggestion but sadly not implemented by microsoft for its inbuilt WPF datagrid. I am upvoting your question for an interesting discussion.

Comment: Strange thing is that I can see the rows using AsQueryable but indeed no columns. So I would agree with @Blam. Or you could try creating the columns manually.

Comment: IQueryable  get me dynamic  query on my base object,
i won't display all properties always.
if the propble is accessible , why it's work on my computer?
only on others it's dosen't work.

Comment: LINQ supports List.  What is your query problem?  You may not be approaching this from the best direction.  Casting from Var to Object just leaves for a lot casting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the WPF DataGrid plays well with IQueryable collections. Instead of `res.AsQueryable()`, try `res.ToList()`.

By using ToList(), you force the query to be evaluated and the results will be dumped into a list, which in this case, will be strongly typed and can be inspected by the DataGrid to generate the columns.